# Browser and web scraper access different sources using the same link?

Tags: scala, xml-parsing, xhtml, web-scraping

I'm currently try to scrape some data from some webpages with scala and eclipse and my problem is that when I look at the source of the page in the browser, the content seems to be very straightforward to read in using scala's xml package:

```
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="de">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>some text</title>

<meta name="keywords" content="some text" />
<meta name="description" content="some text" />
<meta name="robots" content="noodp"/>
<meta name="page-topic" content="some text" />

<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
...
```

But when my little program tries to access the page using the same link to read in the content, it reads the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" />
  <title>some text</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="/favicon.ico" />
  <link href="/res/im.min.css" media="all, handheld" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
...
```

and I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1625)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:633)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1271)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1238)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:260)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1153)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1049)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:962)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
    ...
```

So why do I only have access to some other (mobile?) version of the page I can view in the browser and why do I get such an error message?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like either the server decided your scraper was a mobile browser (probably based on the User-Agent header) and served you the wrong page, or your scraper wasn't logged in so it sent a 403 Forbidden. Does your scraper handle cookies?

Comment: Nope. It does not hadle cookies.